# Ubuntu 23.10 not fully loading in

Tags: boot, lenovo, storage

When I power on my Lenovo Ideapad, my laptop goes to the `/dev/sdXX: clean screen, then goes to the loading screen, then back to the same screen as before and a minute or so in it says it failed to create a new system journal, I already tried fixing it with fsck. When I boot into safe mode or whatever it is called, it doesn't clear any space when I click clear so that can't fix the storage issue. Also, if it matters, this is what the exact screen says:

```
[   0.166632] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/mmcblk1p2: clean, 350613/3751936 files, 14886126/14992128 blocks
[  81.676373] systemd-journald[216]: Failed to create new system journal: No space left on device
```

Comment: Boot into a live USB and make some space by deleting things.

Comment: Your filesystem is okay and doesn't need fixing ... It just appears to be full and you might need to delete some files to free some space.

Answer (score 0):

what organic marble said in the comments worked

"Boot into a live USB and make some space by deleting things." –
Organic Marble